# Include external javascript code in cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I tried to include external javascript code in my cordova app but it doesn't work.

My code as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/api/scripts.js"></script>
```

My whitelist script as following:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you face any errors?

Answer (score 0):

it's better to load the jQuery script from the app library instead external (unlike in web), makes the loading faster.
regarding the script add, 
`<access origin="https://*.website.com/api/scripts.js" launch-external="yes"/>` check if it fixes the build.